# How do I show baseline for 0 data in JPGraph?

Tags: php, jpgraph

I am plotting a bar graph for a set of data which may contain `null` or `0` as the data element.

eg: `[30,12,30,60,30,12,30,0,30,12,30,60,]`

but with JPGraph I am getting output as

[image: output using jpgraph]

I am looking for something like this

[image: expected result]

as seen in img-2, for plot D the data value is 0. but single line is shown as a baseline/base representation.

EDIT: below is the code

```
require_once('jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_bar.php');
//create the graph
$graph = new Graph(512,256); //set the width and the height
$graph->SetScale("textlin"); //set the scale of the graph

$graph->img->SetMargin(40,30,40,40);

$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(["Sept  ","Oct  ","Nov  ","Dec  ","Jan  ","Feb  ","March  ","April  ","May  ","June  ","July  ","Aug  ","Sept  ","Oct  "]);
$graph->xaxis->scale->ticks->Set(100,5);

$graph->xaxis->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);


$data=array(30,12,30,60,30,12,30,0,30,12,30,60,); //prepare the data

// Create the bar plots and add it to the graph
$barplot = new BarPlot($data);
$graph->Add($barplot);

$path = $graph->Stroke();
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you are using to create those graphs along with sample data so other may take your attempt and try to help.

Comment: @Dave,  I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: If you can modify your data and change any zero values to 0.5 they will show up on your plot without changing anything else. That will result in a very small, but visible, bar for the zero values.

Comment: No, that won't help. if few data are 3digit, below 1 data is not plotted.